# Array.Find<List<Status>> Error: List<Status> does not contain a definition for 'StatusID'

Tags: c#, arrays, find

I tried finding a similar issue to this one.. I am wondering if anyone can point out the flaw with my code. I have a `List` called `statuses` of type `Status` class, the class looks like this:

```
public class Status
{
    public int StatusID { get; set; }
    public string StatusDescr { get; set; }
    public string StatusType { get; set; }
}
```

I retrieve an array/list of records from SQL and want to find the StatusDescr using a known StatusID:

```
List<Status> statuses = Status_Get(inputAction, dataDef);
var inputStatusID = fooData["StatusID"];
string statusDescr = Array.Find<List<Status>>(statuses, item => item.StatusID == inputStatusID).StatusDescr;
```

but I get an error on `item.StatusID` in the 3rd line saying:
`'List<Status> does not contain a definition for 'StatusID' and no extension method 'StatusID' accepting a first argument of type 'List<Status>' could be found'`

Obviously this is because StatusID exists on type Status, not `List<Status>`. 
If I change it to `Array.Find<Status>`, I get an error on `statuses` saying:
`Cannot convert from '...List<...DataTypes.View.Status>' to '...DataTypes.View.Status[]'.

Basically I don't care if `statuses` is a List, array, dynamic, etc.. I just want to retrieve the StatusDescr from the Status object with a matching StatusID. 
Any ideas on data types? Should I use something besides `Array.Find`?

**Edit:**
If I take out the data type after `Find` like this:

```
 Array.Find(statuses, item => item.StatusID == inputStatusID).StatusDescr;
```

I get an error on `Find` saying: The type arguments for method 'Array.Find(T[], Predicate)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Comment: Does `Array.Find(statuses, item => item.StatusID == inputStatusID).StatusDescr`work? Without the type constraint. Otherwise you could use a LINQ query like `statuses.Select(i => i.StatusId == inputStatusID).SingleOrDefault()`or something.

Comment: I edited post to respond to your first question. If you think using `Find` is the issue I will try the other ways. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var result = statuses.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.StatusID == inputStatusID);

string statusDescr = result?.StatusDescr;
```

You need something like this.

Here check [**dotnet fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rpEvDm)

Comment: This will probably work, but I get error "Cannot use a lambda as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type". How would the delegate look in this case? Should I change any datatypes?

Comment: @jhhoff02 what is the type of inputStatusID ?Is it int or it is dynamic ?

Comment: Dynamic or var but I could change it. It is also an int though, if that helps, I could use int

Comment: dynamic and var are 2 different things, change the type to int if it is dynamic and be sure that you wrote it correctly.

Comment: @jhhoff02 I add you dotnet fiddle to check it.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.Find` expects an array as the first parameter, but you have a list not an array. You could get an array from a List but it would be better to use `First` LINQ extension method:

```
List<Status> statuses = Status_Get(inputAction, dataDef);
var inputStatusID = fooData["StatusID"];
string statusDescr = statuses.First(item => item.StatusID == inputStatusID).StatusDescr;
```